# OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to understand why this falling apart please. The code below runs fine on pandas `0.17.0` and numpy `1.10.1` (python 2.7)

```
In [1]:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

In [2]:    
df = pd.DataFrame([['01-Nov-2015', 1],['02-Nov-2015', np.Inf],['03-Nov-2015', 4]], columns=('Date','c1'))
#df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df

Out[2]:
    Date         c1
0   01-Nov-2015  1.000000
1   02-Nov-2015  inf
2   03-Nov-2015  4.000000

In [3]:    
df == np.Inf

Out[3]:
    Date    c1
0   False   False
1   False   True
2   False   False
```

However if I uncomment the line `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)` to do the date type conversion and run it again it will drop me the overflow error mentioned in the title of this post.

I initially thought that something happens when one compares a Timestamp (or is it datetime64?) to np.Inf, however that doesnt seem to be the case since the following runs fine

```
In [4]:
pd.to_datetime('5-11-2015') == np.Inf

Out[4]:
False
```

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: This is odd but note that `df['Date'] == np.Inf` will raise an invalid comparison error

Comment: Note that you can compare only c1: `df.c1 == np.Inf` but it doesn't answer why comparing the datetime would raise this exception.

Answer (score -1):

It does look like an issue with datetime. I'd split the calculation and rejoin the datetime later on if I were you, there might be something stranger going on in the underlying code.